# Installing php-PhantomJS on localhost

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, phantomjs

I'm trying to use `php-PhantomJS` on localhost `(XAMPP 1.7.7, PHP: 5.3.8)`, but I cannot run example files and I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client' not found in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\read\test\src\a.php on line 4
>
> Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\read\test\test\JonnyW\PhantomJs\Test\ClientTest.php on
> line 19

Can anybody help in guiding me how to install this script?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.thehackeruniversity.com/2014/01/05/getting-started-with-php-composer/

The instructions on that blog should be fairly easy to follow.

Comment: That's why it's not that good to post external solutions, the link is down